# Partition scheme for two SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I have a 20Gb ssd and new 250Gb ssd. I want to reinstall linux and need to know how its best to partition them to keep them running smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20GB is about right for the root directory ( / ).
Put /home folder on the 250GB SSD.

If you want a separate data partition in case you decide to redo /home, then
make a 50GB /home and 200GB data partitions on the 250GB SDD.
the data partition can be set to auto mount or manually mount.

If booting EFI, then split the 20GB SSD into a 500MB ESP (EFI system partition) and the rest for root.